# Filter IList<T>

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, pass-by-reference, ilist, pass-by-value

```
List<PaymentType> paymentOptions = _PaymentMethods;
```

`_PaymentMethods` is an public property and I'd like to filter a copy of it and store it in the variable `paymentOptions`

```
List<Int32> noInvoice = new List<Int32>(){ 16, 4 , 6 };
foreach (PaymentType pt in paymentOptions)
{
    if(noInvoice.Contains(pt.Id))
    {
        paymentOptions.Remove(pt);
        break;
    }
}
```

But if you run this the second time, the variable `_PaymentMethods` does not contain the removed item anymore.

It seems to go by Reference instead of by value...
I prefer not to copy the list to an array
Should I use Linq or is there an other way?

**EDIT:** I have this now:

```
List<PaymentType> paymentOptions = ShopController.CurrentShop.PaymentMethods;
List<PaymentType> paymentOptionsFiltered = new List<PaymentType>();    

if (haveToFilter)
{
    List<Int32> noInvoice = new List<Int32>() { 16, 4, 6 };

    foreach (PaymentType pt in paymentOptions)
    {
        if (!noInvoice.Contains(pt.Id))
        {
            paymentOptionsFiltered.Add(pt);
        }
    }
    repeaterPaymentOptions.DataSource = paymentOptionsFiltered;
}
else
{
    repeaterPaymentOptions.DataSource = paymentOptions;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to remove all those that match the `noInvoice` list, or just the first one as happens in your code?

Comment: You are right Martinho, but I know that only one of the three will occur at a time. So `Remove` or `RemoveAll` is both fine. But this way alters my unfiltered `_PaymentMethods` also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use LINQ:

```
List<PaymentType> paymentOptionsWithNoInvoice =  
paymentOptions.Where(a=> !noInvoice.Contains(a.Id)).ToList();
```

Comment: This seems the best option. I forgot the `using System.Linq` and therefore the paymentOptions had no Where option since it was not IQueryable. You only forgot the !noInvoice.Contains...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `List<T>` [copy constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0.aspx) and remove from the copy:

```
var paymentOptionsWithNoInvoice = new List<PaymentType>(_PaymentMethods);
paymentOptionsWithNoInvoice.RemoveAll(pt => noInvoice.Contains(pt.Id));
```